# Application authentication azure best field to reference user in local database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, authentication

I begin to test an asp.net mvc application with authication based on azure.
The application is declared in azure and  work properly.
Now i need to store in my application data link to the connected user.
What is the best field to use in my database to make the link between data and users ? For example, Email seems not to be a good idea because it could change ?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Your question is all over the board - Azure, ASP.Net MVC, Database. Could you narrow down the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion.

I find the answer. The objectid seems to be the more appropriate way to identify user and store in local database information about user. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32510679/getting-users-token-subject-identifier-sub-from-within-azure-ad) explain the way to get it.

Thanks