# B2C custom policy with two IDP, but only one allows singup

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I've configurated a B2C Userflow to permit login from an external IDP based on Keycloak and an Azure AD B2B configurated as OpenID IDP.

To connect the B2B, I've mapped the sub claim. As I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32510679/getting-users-token-subject-identifier-sub-from-within-azure-ad), sub isn't present in User information, but I can obtain it only from token.

I need to prevent sign up for Keycloak users, but let B2B user do. With user flows I can't do in the same flow. Can I do with a B2C custom policy?

Comment: Custom policies should allow what you need, or you could make a separate signin flow and a separate signup flow (and allow only the IdPs there that you want). Your apps would then have to support two flows of course.

Comment: Thank you, I will learn more about the custom policy and how to configure my workflow.